# how to get real size of elements in the tab panel when user selects tab

Tags: jquery-ui

What I want to do is getting width and height of elements inside of the selected ui-tab-pane when user selects tab header.
But width and height are always zero because ui-tab-pane is still display:none even though user clicked tab header.
Is there any fancy way to get real size of ui-tab-pane?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself.

Don't use 'tabsselect' event when you need to manipulate ui-tab-panel.
Use 'li a' click event as below

```
$('#tabs li a').click(function () {
   // do something to manipulate ui-tab-panel
});
```